# What is the maximum size I can use in "shmget" system call? (To get shared memory)

Tags: c, shared-memory

I am writing a simple program to allocate shared memory,
Below is the sample code for shmget,

```
#define SHM_SIZE 1024

main(int argc,char **argv)
{
        int shmId,choice;
        key_t key=8888;
        char *shmPtr;
        size_t memSize;

        shmId=shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
        if(shmId == -1)
        {
                perror("shmget");
                exit(1);
        }
```

Above code is working properly without any error,

Now, When i change **SHM_SIZE** to **1024*1024*1024**
Then i am getting error in **shmget**

```
Error : 
shmget: Invalid argument
```

Can anyone please help why is that?

Am i allocating more than the max?

Comment: Did you read the [shmem man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget)? "EINVAL. A new segment was to be created and size < SHMMIN or size > SHMMAX".

Comment: @kaylum  Thank you for your reply, I have already checked SHMMAX
using "cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax" and it is "4GB",
As you can see in my program i am trying to allocate only "1GB" still i am getting error,
Can please help in this?

Comment: SHM segments are global resources, once created successfully you need to explicitly remove them. Using the same name it cannot be created twice. (see `man ipcs` and `man ipcrm`).

Comment: Fair enough. How about the rest of that error description from the man page: "A new segment was to be created and size < SHMMIN or size > SHMMAX, or no new segment was to be created, a segment with given key existed, but size is greater than the size of that segment. ". The first time you run `shmget` it will create the shared memory. But it will not delete it. So next time you run the `shmget` with a greater size it will get an EINVAL as described in the second part of that error description.

Comment: @alk Thank you so much, It worked. I was not aware of that, Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling the comments into an answer. The [shmget man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shmget) describes the possible causes of an `EINVAL` error:

> A new segment was to be created and size < SHMMIN or size > SHMMAX, or no new segment was to be created, a segment with given key existed, but size is greater than the size of that segment.

Since your system is configured with a `SHMMAX` greater than the requested size the error must be due to the second reason. Which likely occured because you first ran the program with the smaller size. Since shared memory is not automatically removed when the process that creates it exits that shared memory will still exist when the program is run again with the larger size. As described in the error description, it is not permitted to call `shmget` on an existing shared memory region with a larger size.